# Replacement for LIBOR Market Model (LMM)?

Tags: interest-rates, libor, sofr, libor-cessation, libor-market-model

With the transition from LIBOR to SOFR, will the LIBOR Market Model be replaced by a new model?  Perhaps this has already happened.  If yes, what is this new model?  If not, will the LIBOR Market Model "live on" after the transition to SOFR?

Thanks!

Comment: This [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3330240) explains that LMM will live on and be perfectly fine for the new RFR rates also. Ps: the authors of the paper were nominated for "quant of the year" award for that paper, it's a really good paper to read.

Comment: @JanStuller In this paper backward-looking forward rates (term rates deducted from SOFR) are modelled as well as forward-looking forward rates (defining in the OIS swap rates, to quote the authors), right ?

Comment: @Olórin: correct.

Comment: @JanStuller So this model can diffuse at the same time backward-looking forward rates of a given tenor T and forward-looking forward rates defined in the OIS swap rate manner. But what about if for instance I need a model diffusing at the same time ESTR 3M (backward-looking) forward rates and EURIBOR 3M (forward-looking) forward rates ? The $r_t$ from the paper cannot be used to model both, right ? Unless the EURIBOR3M could be defined as in the old single-curve manner, using only the RFR ESTR, which it obviously cannot, as far as I know.